# Data frame list - Adding a new column based on data frame name

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list of dataframes, each one with several columns. An example of my data could be:

```
Ind_ID<-rep(1:15)
Mun<-sample(15)
T_i<-paste0("D",rep(1:5))
data<-cbind(Ind_ID,Mun,T_i)
data<-data.frame(data)
mylist<-split(data,data$T_i)
str(mylist)

List of 5
 $ D1:'data.frame':     3 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Ind_ID: Factor w/ 15 levels "1","10","11",..: 1 12 3
  ..$ Mun   : Factor w/ 15 levels "1","10","11",..: 3 10 7
  ..$ T_i   : Factor w/ 5 levels "D1","D2","D3",..: 1 1 1
 $ D2:'data.frame':     3 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Ind_ID: Factor w/ 15 levels "1","10","11",..: 8 13 4
  ..$ Mun   : Factor w/ 15 levels "1","10","11",..: 14 11 5
  ..$ T_i   : Factor w/ 5 levels "D1","D2","D3",..: 2 2 2
...
 $ D5:'data.frame':     3 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Ind_ID: Factor w/ 15 levels "1","10","11",..: 11 2 7
  ..$ Mun   : Factor w/ 15 levels "1","10","11",..: 4 12 2
  ..$ T_i   : Factor w/ 5 levels "D1","D2","D3",..: 5 5 5
```

I want to add a new column with the same name as the data frame.  My expected output is:

```
$D1
   Ind_ID Mun T_i  D1
1       1  11  D1 NA
6       6   4  D1 NA
11     11  15  D1 NA

$D2
   Ind_ID Mun T_i  D2
2       2   8  D2 NA
7       7   5  D2 NA
12     12  13  D2 NA

....

$D5
   Ind_ID Mun T_i  D5
5       5  12  D5 NA
10     10   6  D5 NA
15     15  10  D5 NA
```

My failed attempts include:

```
nam<-as.list(names(mylist))
fun01 <- function(x,y){cbind(x, y = rep(1, nrow(x)))}
a1<-lapply(mylist, fun01,nam)
str(a1) # This generates a new column with the name "y" in all cases

fun02 <- function(x,y){x= cbind(x, a = rep(1, nrow(x)));names(x)[4] <- y}
a2<-lapply(mylist, fun02,nam)
str(a2) # It changes the data frames
```

Any help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through all the dataframes with a lapply call and create your new column with something like this:

```
newlist = lapply(1:length(mylist), function(i){

  # Get the dataframe and the name 
  tmp_df = mylist[[i]]
  tmp_name = names(mylist)[i]

  # Create a new column with all NAs
  tmp_df[,ncol(tmp_df) + 1] = NA

  # Rename the newly created column
  colnames(tmp_df)[ncol(tmp_df)] = tmp_name

  # Return the df
  return(tmp_df)
})
```

Comment: Wow that was fast! Thank you so much @Lorenzo-Rossi

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: You could use `Map()`.  First we can write a little function for the iteration.

```
f <- function(df, nm) cbind(df, setNames(data.frame(NA), nm))
Map(f, mylist, names(mylist))
```

Option 2: You could live dangerously and do

```
Map("[<-", mylist, names(mylist), value = NA)
```